# How to make an alert appear after every button click, and disappear after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout, alert

.JS

```
 var alert = document.getElementById('notify').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML="";
      },3000);
```

HTML

```
<div class="alert alert notify text-center" id="notify" role="alert">
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Saved!
</div>
```

Currently my project is meant for students to add/delete courses from their student schedules when making their schedules for certain terms. I have a save alert that I want to appear eveytime the student adds or deletes from the cart. I also want the sav message to go away after 3 seconds.

Comment: You haven't stated what's wrong with the code you've posted, but I'll take a stab at it: why are you clearing the `innerHTML` of `#notify`? You won't be able to re-use `#notify` without resetting its content. Why have you opted for this route instead of setting the `style.display` attribute to something other than `block`?

Comment: At the beginning you are making `#notify` visible, but why are you clearing its `innerHTML`when you are wanting it to disappear? You can use ```document.getElementById('notify').style.display = 'none';```, Just the opposite of what you did earlier to make it visible.

Comment: We need some more code to diagnose the problem and offer a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emptying the `innerHTML` of the element, you should set its CSS display property to "none". You also have to add an event listener to the button (which is conspicuously missing from your HTML).

```js
document.querySelector("#save").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  document.querySelector("#notify").style.display = "";
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector("#notify").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<button id="save">Save</button>
<div class="alert alert notify text-center" id="notify" role="alert" style="display: none;">
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Saved!
</div>
```